# Conda is not recognized

Tags: python

[Solution]
anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet.

This solution work to me, in power shell, put the command bellow:

(Get-Content $PROFILE | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch 'anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe' }) | Set-Content $PROFILE

Only post solution.

Comment: So what is your actual question?

Comment: is it bash ? it does not looks like a pure python problem.